# Graph titles are printed one by one

Tags: python, matplotlib

Graph titles are printed one by one.
How can I solve this problem??

This is my code.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.125, bottom=0.1,  right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.4)
n = 1

for idx, i in enumerate(top_10_df_event_copy['Code'].unique()):
    top_10_df_event_copy_list[i] = pd.Series(winsorize(top_10_df_event_copy_list[i].values, limits=[0, 0.1]))
    stl = seasonal_decompose(top_10_df_event_copy_list[i].values, freq=3)
    plt.title(f"{i}", fontsize=15)
    ax = plt.subplot(4,3,n)
    
    ax.plot(stl.seasonal + stl.trend)
    ax.plot(stl.observed, color='red', alpha=0.5)
    n += 1
    print(i)
    

plt.show()
```

i = [90001302, 90001341, 90001441, 90001443, 90001521, 90001541, 90001542, 90001582, 90001602, 90001622]

Finally print(i)

> 90001302
> 90001341
> 90001441
> 90001443
> 90001521
> 90001541
> 90001542
> 90001582
> 90001602
> 90001622

but graph is printed like this picture.

There are 10 titles in 10 graphs, but in reality only 9 titles are output in 10 graphs.

plz help..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPsCM.png)

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @PaulH There are 10 titles in 10 graphs, but in reality only 9 titles are output in 10 graphs..

Comment: use `ax.set_title` instead of `plt.title`. The `plt` state machine is using the "current" axes object, which is always the previous axes after the first iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the object-oriented interface to set the titles instead of the pyplot state machine:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(25,10))

for i in range(10):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 3, i+1)
    ax.set_title(f"This is axes #{i+1}")
    
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.125, bottom=0.1,  right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks !!!!